# Make isotropic tensor anisotropic and viceversa?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, rotations

Let's say I have an isotropic tensor in 3D [the identity matrix] of the form
$$I=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
I understand that this tensor is invariant to rotations meaning that the standard tensor rotation would leave the initial tensor unchanged:

$$ I=RIR^T$$

My question is, what is the correct way to make this tensor such that it only has components like this:
$$I'=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Or this:
$$I'=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Or an in-between case such as:
$$I'=\begin{bmatrix}0.3&0&0\\0&0.3&0\\0&0&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$ [These are just random values]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!